# SQLite error for migration without default value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I have a Laravel project with a MySQL database, and my migration works perfectly, but my problem is when I change the MySQL connection to SQLite and run the migration, I get an error for fields that do not have a default value. What is the solution for this? I found this solution for that is dirty, and I have to add this condition to many migrations.

```
$driver = Schema::connection($this->getConnection())
    ->getConnection()->getDriverName();
Schema::table('proposals', function (Blueprint $table) use ($driver) {
    if ($driver === 'sqlite') {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('final_amount')->default('');
    } else {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('final_amount');
    }
});
```

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Cannot add a NOT NULL column with
> default value NULL

Comment: `unsignedBigInteger` but you set default to empty string? try use 0 instead.

Comment: @BagusTesa problem is something else . read the text please

Comment: sure, it says *"General error: 1 Cannot add a NOT NULL column with **default value NULL.**"*

Comment: @connectaadmin it would be faster for you to try his suggestion than arguing it. If you want to add a new column in an existing table with entries, either set a **valid** default or set it nullable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a new column in an existing table with entries, either set a valid default or set it nullable

```
 $driver = Schema::connection($this->getConnection())->getConnection()->getDriverName();
    Schema::table('proposals', function (Blueprint $table) use ($driver){
        if ($driver === 'sqlite'){
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('final_amount')->default(0);
        }else{
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('final_amount')->nullable();
        }
    });
```